# Get typedef of current class

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, macros, typedef

I'm currently using boost::intrusive_ptr together with my GUI classes.
Although this is more or less a convenience question, is there a proper way to get the typename of the current class?
The reason I'm asking is that I have a macro for typedef'ing the different pointer types:

```
#define INTRUSIVE_PTR_TYPEDEFS(CLASSNAME) typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<CLASSNAME> Ptr; \
typedef boost::intrusive_ptr<const CLASSNAME> CPtr; \
typedef CLASSNAME* WeakPtr; \
typedef const CLASSNAME* CWeakPtr;

...

class Widget
{
public:
    INTRUSIVE_PTR_TYPEDEFS(Widget);
    ...
};

class Button : public Widget
{
public:
    INTRUSIVE_PTR_TYPEDEFS(Button);
    ...
};
```

It would be much more comfortable to have `CLASSNAME` automatically deduced so you could simply copy'n'paste it into the class body. I'm using the compiler shipped with Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first question is why hide all types in those typedefs. I find it clearer to use the real type name.

Comment: In my opinion it's much shorter and faster to write.
`boost::intrusive_ptr<Button>` isn't much of a favor for my eyes if I go through my source.

Comment: isn't it? It's pretty plain to see from that that it is an intrusive pointer to a Button. Encountering something of type `Ptr` tells me nothing other than that it *probably* refers to some kind of pointer-like type. Source code is supposed to be readable. Readability isn't just facilitated by making the code short. It is best achieved by including the information that the reader needs.

Comment: @jalf: That's your point on hiding maybe important implementation details. I actually named it `Ptr` because it's shorter than `RefPtr` or something like that. Although chances are that nobody besides me will ever read the source or get the binaries, I wanted to encourage the use of `Ptr` as the always valid intrusive pointer compared to `WeakPtr`, which suggests the opposite.
I admit that probably I'm too lazy with my undescriptive typedefs, but my actual question was about getting the this_type, not purely because I would love to copy'n'paste the macro.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, that's not possible to do in C++.

Comment: Even in C++11 it's still not possible, even with all the fancy new decltype and auto keywords and such. Slightly disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, one idea I have is to call constructor and typename on this pointer... Another way could be to create a template metaprogram for creating classes, which will do the typedefs as well.

Comment: That's actually what I wanted to do, but after having a first glance at Boost.MPL, I couldn't find what I was looking for. Could you give me a hint on that?